# Find and flatten overlapping time intervals in ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, time

I am trying to do some downtime calculations for an application. What I have is a giant array of hashes that show when different parts of the application were down. The hash includes a Start time and an End time. The problem is that some of these downtimes can overlap. How can I go through the array of hashes and find time intervals which overlap.

```
times = [{"timefrom"=>1461693247, "timeto"=>1461693307},
         {"timefrom"=>1462363987, "timeto"=>1462364607},
         {"timefrom"=>1462364037, "timeto"=>1462366037}]
```

So for example, given the array above, `times[1]` and `times[2]` overlap. So ideally what I would like to do is merge them so that they form one long outage. I.E.

```
times[1] = { "timefrom" => times[1]["timefrom"], "timeto" => times[2]["timeto"] }
```

Comment: Might more than 2 timeslices overlap? Is an input sorted by `"timefrom"`?

Comment: @mudasobwa in theory they could all overlap. Super unlikely but they COULD. And yes, sorted by `timefrom`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd like to see your effort toward solving the problem. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. Also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 is useful to read.

Comment: What is the Ruby issue you are facing in solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the elements `g` (hashes) of `times` are ordered by `g["timefrom"]`.

```
def combine_times(times)
  times[1..-1].each_with_object([times.first]) do |g,a|
    if g["timefrom"] < a.last["timeto"]
      a[-1]["timeto"] = [ a[-1]["timeto"], g["timeto"] ].max
    else
      a << g
    end
  end
end

times = [{"timefrom"=>1461693247, "timeto"=>1461693307},

         {"timefrom"=>1462363987, "timeto"=>1462364607},
         {"timefrom"=>1462364037, "timeto"=>1462366037}]
```

The line spacing shows how the elements of `times` should be grouped.

```
combine_times(times)
  #=> [{"timefrom"=>1461693247, "timeto"=>1461693307}, (times[0])
  #    {"timefrom"=>1462363987, "timeto"=>1462366037}] (combines times[1..2])
```

Another example:

```
times = [{"timefrom"=>10, "timeto"=>20},
         {"timefrom"=>12, "timeto"=>15},

         {"timefrom"=>22, "timeto"=>30},
         {"timefrom"=>28, "timeto"=>32},
         {"timefrom"=>29, "timeto"=>29},

         {"timefrom"=>32, "timeto"=>40},

         {"timefrom"=>42, "timeto"=>50},
         {"timefrom"=>43, "timeto"=>46}]

combine_times(times)
  #=> [{"timefrom"=>10, "timeto"=>20}, (combines times[0..1])
  #    {"timefrom"=>22, "timeto"=>32}, (combines times[2..4])
  #    {"timefrom"=>32, "timeto"=>40}, (times[5])
  #    {"timefrom"=>42, "timeto"=>50}] (combines times[6..7])
```

Comment: Nice! Following your solution, I was able to improve a perl solution I was working on.